# Is Adhyanta Prabhu mentioned in any scriptures?

Tags: scripture, identification-request, hanuman, ganesha

In the picture given below, Ganesha and Hanuman fused into a unique form, Adhyanta Prabhu.
[image]

I want to know about this form. So, my question is, Do any scriptures mentions this form?